# Tarski’s fixed-point theorem and the existence of minimal fixed points

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(X,\geq)$ be a partially ordered set. Suppose that

- any non-empty subset of $X$ has a supremum in $X$ with respect to the order $\geq$;
- $X$ has a maximum element: $\exists \overline x\in X:\overline x\geq x\,\,\forall x\in X$;
- $X$ has a minimum element: $\exists \underline x\in X:x\geq\underline x\,\,\forall x\in X$.

Let $f:X\to X$ be a non-decreasing function; that is, for any $x,y\in X$, $x\geq y$ implies that $f(x)\geq f(y)$.

Let $\mathscr F\equiv\{x\in X\,|\,x=f(x)\}$ be the set of fixed points of $f$.

Now, Tarski’s fixed-point theorem implies that $\mathscr F$ is not empty. It is also easily proved that $\mathscr F$ has a maximum element.

> My question is: does $\mathscr F$ necessarily admit a **minimum** element as well?

Note that the existence of infima of non-empty subsets of $X$ has *not* been assumed, unlike the existence of suprema.

Any hints, either towards a proof or towards a counterexample, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I misunderstood. My bad.

Comment: The existence of infima does not have to be assumed, it **follows** from the existence of suprema. Consider any set $A\subseteq X.$ Let $B$ be the set of all lower bounds for $A.$ Then $B\ne\emptyset$ since $X$ has a minimum element. It is easy to see that the supremum of $B$ is also the infimum of $A.$ So the answer to your question is yes, $\mathscr F$ has both a maximum and a minimum element.

Comment: @bof Awesome answer, thank you very much! Please put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of infima does not have to be assumed, it *follows* from the existence of suprema. Consider any set $A\subseteq X.$ Let $B$ be the set of all lower bounds for $A.$ Then $B\ne\emptyset$ since $X$ has a minimum element. It is easy to see that the supremum of $B$ is also the infimum of $A.$ So the answer to your question is yes, $\mathscr F$ has both a maximum and a minimum element.